# WPF ScrollBar: both horizontal and vertical from one template?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, styles, controltemplate, scrollviewer

I have a requirement to retemplate the `ScrollBar` so that only one `Template` is required, instead of separate horizontal and vertical ones. The designer's assertion is that the `ScrollBar` can be rotated on a `Trigger` (Orientation = Horizontal), and the commands swapped on the buttons.

Since the single `Template` is set up as a `Grid` with rows, the horizontal `ScrollBar` is stuck in the center of the view when rotated, showing just the left and right buttons. This seems to be because the height of the center * row is the height of the track area, so it won't stretch. Binding in the `Trigger` to the height of something like the parent `ScrollViewer` `ActualWidth` causes the usual stackoverflow.

Any thoughts? I presume there's a reason all the examples have a horizontal and vertical templates separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it out:

```
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">

            <!-- Rotate the ScrollBar from Vertical to Horizontal -->
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="gLayoutRoot">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <!-- Change Track Orientation back to Vertical -->
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="IsDirectionReversed" Value="false"/>

            <!-- Change the commands to do Horizontal commands -->
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" TargetName="DecreaseRepeat"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" TargetName="IncreaseRepeat"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" TargetName="PageDown"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" TargetName="PageUp"/>

        </Trigger>
```

Then in the style set everything to Stretch or Auto.

```
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/> 
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
```

Fortunately one of those things that worked out.

Comment: After all this, it's been decided the rotation produces unacceptable blurriness, so there's a separate horizontal scrollbar template now. Like I had before. :)